# Speed of finding the number of digits in a number

Tags: java

I use two processes through which I determine the number of digits a number has.

given x is an int value

1.

```
int digits = ("" + x).length();
```

2.

```
int digits = 0;
while(x > 0)
{
    digits ++;
    x /= 10;
}
```

Why is the 2nd process usually faster?

Comment: Hmm, both would not work for negative numbers though.

Comment: @ScaryWombat In that case, we can just take the absolute value of the number before trying one/both of the above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Would doing an abs be quicker or slower (being the crux of the question) than my below code?

Comment: For positive numbers there's `(int)Math.log10(x)+1`.  Not certain how that compares in terms of cycles though.

Comment: The first does everything the second does and more, as well as creating garbage, so it must be slower. `(int)Math.log10(x)+1` will be much faster than either. Warning: years ago someone on the Sun Java forums described this technique as 'untested'. You couldn't make this stuff up.

Answer (score 4):

Converting a number into a string is very similar to the division algorithm, but has more overhead because it has to create a string. Read the [source code](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Integer.java#L437) for `Integer.toString` and you'll find a loop similar to your second process.

*The second process is faster because the first process includes the second process!*

Answer (score 3):

The first method requires first converting the integer to a string, and then taking its length.  There is an overhead involved in doing this conversion.  On the other hand, the second version requires only division on the original integer.  The division operation should generally be very fast, and can happen under the hood directly on the registers of the system which is running Java.